# Extremely weird behaviour of return statement : Java

Tags: java

OK I have a weird problem. The code is as follows :
The method name is `returnMultiPartHeading`

```
if (recursionCount > 6 || i == list.size() - 1)
            return -1;
        multiPartHeading = multiPartHeading + " " + list.get(i + 1).getText();
        Token token = new Token();
        token.setText(multiPartHeading);
        if (isHeadingType(token)) {
            System.out.println("found " + multiPartHeading);
            System.out.println("returning ...");
            System.out.println("I is " + (i + 1));
            return (i + 1);
        } else {
            returnMultiPartHeading(list, i + 1, multiPartHeading,
                    ++recursionCount);

        }
        System.out.println("returning -1");
        return -1;
    }
```

The output is for a sample run is :

```
found xyz
returning...
I is 2
returning -1
```

why is this happening?? the `if (isHeadingType(token))` evaluates to `true` , prints the two messages and then it totally skips the `return i+1` and goes to `return -1` instead.  In the place I called it, I get  -1 as the returned value instead of getting 2. Why is this happening?? Never saw this behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling this method twice? Put a println before the 'isHeadingType'.

Comment: I doubt the class is not getting compiled properly. May be ur are still referring to old class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because in your `else` block, you don't actually *return* the result of the recursive call.  You just call the method, ignore its result, and then fall through to the section below (with the `return -1`).

You need to change your else block to

```
else {
     return returnMultiPartHeading(list, i + 1, multiPartHeading,
                ++recursionCount);
}
```

(assuming that your method really is called `returnMultiPartHeading`, which somehow doesn't sound right)

Comment: he probably made a typo  and thats not the problem

Comment: I don't think this is the problem... He is wondering why the function execute the println in the if block without returning. It returns, indeed.

Comment: @SteveL I'm not convinced - looking at the code, the only possible way the `println("returning -1")` statement can be reached, is if the flow has passed through the if-else block.  In the `if` case, there is a definitive `return` statement.  So the execution in question **must** have gone through the `else` block and not returned.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle ,oh I didn't noticed that

Comment: Thanks. I had to totally forgotten about recursion. For a minute there I thought I had found a bug in Java :P and yea the method name is `returnMultiPartHeading`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like two calls are performed, the first wrote

```
found xyz
returning...
I is 2
```

and the second

```
returning -1
```

as it is a recursive method I think thats the reason

Comment: Thanks! Had totally ignored recursion!

Answer (score 1):

The `if` block is the second recursive call, which returns to the first recursive call, which was probably called by the `else` block. In the `else` block you do not return the value. Hence it skips out and returns -1.

Comment: Thanks,this was the problem